# electrum JsonRPC Invalid request

Tags: python, request

I'm trying to use [electrum wallet](https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/console.html)

I have this code :

```
import json
import requests

if __name__ == "__main__":
    headers = {'content-type': "application/json", 'cache-control': "no-cache"}
    payload = json.dumps({"method": 'listaddresses', "params": []})
    url = f"http://127.0.0.1:7777"

    print(payload)
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers,
                                auth=('user', 'mypass'))
    print(response)
    print(response.text)
    print(response.json)
```

But i got this error :

```
<Response [500]>
Invalid Request
```

I should get an error, but not a 500 error.
It's not lot of info :/ Do you have any idea of what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: The request is formed correctly. So it must be an issue with the server not being able to handle something in the request, is the payload correct?

Comment: Ok :/ i'll continue to investigate on serveur side then, thank you

Answer (score 0):

after night i found the error.

The payload should be like this :

```
payload = json.dumps({"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"curltext", "method": method, "params": params})
```

with jsonrpc & id

Comment: I get a 403 error?